# generic stored procedure in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, generics, plsql

I want to write a PLSQL stored procedure that accepts a table name as argument.  This table is source table.  Now inside my procedure i want to manipulate the fields of that table.
EX: I want to insert the records of this source table into another target table  whose name is `XYZ_<source table name>`.  The column names for  source and target tables are the  same.  But there may be some extra fields in target table.   How do i do it?   The order of column  names is not same.

Comment: Provide the update statement you want to run, with placeholders for the variables.

Comment: @omg ponies: thanks for replying .Can u provied me some sample code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to build the INSERT statement dynamically.

```
create or replace procedure gen_insert 
   (p_src_table in user_tables.table_name%type
    , p_no_of_rows out pls_integer) 
is
    col_str varchar2(16000);
begin
    for rec in ( select column_name
                        , column_id
                 from user_tab_columns
                 where table_name = p_src_table
                 order by column_id )
    loop
        if rec.column_id != 1 then
            col_str := col_str || ',' || rec.column_name;
        else
            col_str := rec.column_name;
        end if:
    end loop;
    execute immediate 'insert into xyz_' || p_src_table || '('
                           || col_str || ')'
                           || ' select ' || col_str 
                           || ' from ' || p_src_table;
    p_no_of_rows := sql%rowcount;
end;
/
```

Obviously you may want to include some error handling and other improvements.

**edit**

Having edited your question I see you have a special requirement for naming the target table which was obscured by the SO formatting.

Comment: @apc: Theat was great.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Dynamic SQL. Here's a link with basic info on [Oracle Dynamic SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm)

Comment: +1 correct.  One can't use query parameters for table names, so dynamic SQL is the only solution.